# Is the use of "at any time" right here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, phrase-usage

> His weird interests change so rapidly that it's hard to tell what he likes **at** **any time**.

What I mean is:

> His weird interests change so rapidly that it's hard to tell **what** **his current ones** (interests) **are**.

But *any time* is more commonly used in cases like:

> 1. You can call me any time.
> 2. I can handle him anytime.

in the sense of "always" or "without exception or doubt". So—

> #### **Does '*at any time*' fit in this context? And is '*at any time*' grammatical here? Is it idiomatic enough? If not, how would native speakers say this instead?**

Comment: The usual phrase is *at any given time* or *at any given moment*. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22at%20any%20given%20time%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en Another way of putting it is "You can never tell what he's going to be interested in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of

> at any time

is correct and understandable to mean *something* is not predictable.

> The weather may change **at any time**.
>   She can change her mind *at any moment*.

However, in your example, your intent is to *capture* his *state of liking*, so as Tᴚoɯɐuo suggests

> His weird interests change so rapidly that it's hard to tell what he likes at any *given* time.

can be said, and would be equivalent to

> His weird interests *can* change **at any time**.

which is also the same as your original sentence without "**at any time**", where the temporalness is implied.

> His weird interests change so rapidly that it's hard to tell what he likes.

Comment: Question edited.